# Javascript change div color on click and back on second click

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change color of a div depending on initial color on first click, and change it back on second click.
It's working on the first click, but on second it still sees the div having the initial color... like the property doesn't update. Thanks!

```
<script>

function change(div){ 
  if (div.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(252,198,162)")    
{
  div.style.background="rgb(220,20,60)";
}
else
{
  div.style.background="rgb(252,198,162)";
}
}
</script>

<div class="cell_l" id="mydiv" style= "background-color: rgb(252,198,162);" onclick="change(this);"></div>
```

Comment: It's off-topic because please learn to use debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the assignment operator `=` instead of `==` inside your `if` statement.

Make the change:

```
if (div.style.backgroundColor == "rgb(252, 198, 162)")
```

Also, `div.style.backgroundColor` returns back the rgb color with spaces after the commas as such:

```
rgb(252, 198, 162)
```

I made the change as well above.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/11r7L39y/

As @nicael mentioned, **Learn to use the console. Right click -> Inspect -> Console.** In this case there would have been no console error, but for your future reference keep that in mind.